# Adding a remove item function that is inserted with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an add to cart functionality and I am trying to create a remove from cart button. The problem I am having is getting the remove button to be unique to each cart item. It is currently functioning very funny, clicking the first item in the cart deletes all of the other items, and if I select a cart item other than the first one it deletes a different one. How can I make this work? I want to remove the entire LI element upon click.

```
let gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
let ul = document.querySelector(".footer-container");

let num = 0;


gridItems.forEach((item) => {

  const button = item.querySelector(".add-btn");

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {

    ul.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `<li class="footer-items">
      <button class="remove-item">X</button>
      <div class="side-by-side">     
      ${
        item.querySelector(".title").textContent
      } <img class="cart-image" src="${item
        .querySelector(".bike-image")
        .getAttribute("src")}"/></div> <span class="cart-price">${
        item.querySelector(".item-price").textContent
      }</span> </li>`
    );

//My attempt at removing each item

    document
      .querySelector(".remove-item")
      .addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.querySelector(".footer-items").remove();
      });

    
  });
});
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".remove-item")` only ever targets the first button. Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead. E.g., use an [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Use e.g. `addEventListener("click", ({target}) => { if(target.matches(".remove-item")){ target.closest(".footer-items").remove(); } });` (see browser compat) or jQuery’s `.on`.

Comment: @CodeBug The question already contains _“`My attempt at removing each item`”_.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+remove+button+list+item) of [delete specific list item from unordered list when delete button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50524683/4642212).

Comment: have a look at this, https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/v8k7sp21/

Comment: @user4642212 I was asking him minimal working code(ex: along with HTML)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution to the problem by creating a for each loop and targeting the parentNode selector for each item and removing it.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".remove-item").forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener("click", function () {
        item.parentNode.remove();
      });
    });
```